# How can i get value from select option using ajax and php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have 2 select box option, city and district. I use ajax go get district name when I choose on the city. For this process I have succeed but when I click submit I get the error message Undefined index: district ,as this picture you can see
[result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjU36.jpg).

Here is my ajax code:

```
 $(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#city").change(function() {
        var search_id = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "search.php",
            method: "post",
            data: {search_id:search_id},
            success: function(data){
                $("#district").html(data);
            }
        })
    });
});
```

Here is HTML code:

```html
   

 <form action="" method="post">
    select city:
    <select name="city" id="city">
     <option value="1">Phnom Penh</option>
     <option value="2">Kampong Soam</option>
      <option value="3">Siem Reap</option>
    </select>

    select district:
    <select name="distrcit" name="district" id="district">
     <option>Select District</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
```

Here is PHP code:

```html
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 echo $_POST['city'];
 echo $_POST['district'];
}

 ?>

//ajax request
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['search_id'])){
 $search_id = $database->escape_string($_POST['search_id']);

 if(!empty($search_id)){
  // $output = array();
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM district WHERE ref_id = '$search_id'";
  $districts = District::find_this_query($sql);
  foreach($districts as $district){
   // echo $district->id;
   // echo $district->district_name;
   $output .= "<option value='{$district->id}'>{$district->district_name}</option>";
  }

  echo $output;
 }
 
 }
?>
```

Comment: Nothing with ajax and PHP but you have a problem in HTML with select case, you have "name" twice

Comment: Why you have got double `name="""` parameter in this line: `<select name="distrcit" name="district" id="district">`

Comment: oh my god, I really didn't check the name. now it work! Thank you much :) Lorenzo and Pes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set name twice in select box. assign name only once:

so make it:

```
<select name="district" id="district">
    <option>Select District</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Oh dear, it work. I'm so mistake, but anyway thank you. very thank for that :)

Answer (score 1):

In the HTML you have declared name attributes 2 times:

```
<select name="distrcit" name="district" id="district">
```

Please replace with:

```
<select name="district" id="district">
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this way is not very clean, you may create an ajax request returning values in json format and then append resultats in the select tag using

```
new Option(text, value);
```

Answer (score 1):

please define name one time only :

```
<select name="district" id="district">
<option>Select District</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
   

 <form action="" method="post">
    select city:
    <select name="city" id="city">
     <option value="1">Phnom Penh</option>
     <option value="2">Kampong Soam</option>
      <option value="3">Siem Reap</option>
    </select>

    select district:
    <select name="distrcit" name="district" id="district">
     <option>Select District</option>
    </select>

    <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: Please support your answer with explanation. Apparently code only options are not very useful.